# Unable to parse user_media object returned from Instagram API

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am getting a list of recent user media from the Instagram API. I am getting the data back, but for some reason am unable to parse the object by the usual method.

This is the method that makes the API call and returns the object:

```
function getRecent(user_id, access_token, count) {
  request
    .get(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/${user_id}/media/recent/?access_token=${access_token}&count=${count}`, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('subscriptions.js 47 error: ' + err)
      }
      console.log('subscriptions.js 49 response.statusCode = ' + response.statusCode)
      console.log('subscriptions.js 50 body = ' + body)
    })
}
```

The last console log, for body, returns:

```
subscriptions.js 50 body = {"pagination": {}, 
    "data": [{"id": "1638720960483714658_6291666599", 
       "user": {"id": "6291666599", 
       "full_name": "metoo", 
       "profile_picture": "https://..." etc.}
```

but if I log `body.data` or `body["data"]` each return undefined

This makes no sense to me. Why am I unable to access the object in the normal ways?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe `body` is a string. So `JSON.parse(body).data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `body` is a string, you have to `JSON.parse` it to get an actual object:

```
function getRecent(user_id, access_token, count) {
  request
    .get(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/${user_id}/media/recent/?access_token=${access_token}&count=${count}`, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('subscriptions.js 47 error: ' + err)
      }
      console.log('subscriptions.js 49 response.statusCode = ' + response.statusCode)
      console.log('subscriptions.js 50 body = ' + body)

      const json = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log('Yay! An actual object:', json)
      console.log('And its .data:', json.data)
    })
}
```

In fact request library can do this for you [if you call it with `json: true`](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):

```
function getRecent(user_id, access_token, count) {
  request
    .get({
      url: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/${user_id}/media/recent/?access_token=${access_token}&count=${count}`,
      json: true
    }, function(err, response, body) {
      // here body should be an object already
    })
}
```

Comment: You concatenate an object with a string using `+` operator. That's why you get `[object Object]` there, it is intended behavior. Try to use `,` instead of `+` (like I do in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to Instagram [API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self), `/media/recent/` returns a JSON response.

You need to parse the JSON. Try

```
JSON.parse(body)
```